# Setting background color of listcell but keeping :hover :selected background colors

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I have a `ListView` and `ListCells`. On each `ListCell` I do `setStyle(-fx-background-color: #000000)`.

The problem is this overwrites the ":hover", ":selected"... background of the cell, but I want to keep them.

Is there a solution to just overwrite the default background-color without a hover or a focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick solution will be

```
cell.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: red");
```

where `-fx-control-inner-background` is not a JavaFX CSS property, but a predefined color in caspian.css (for JavaFX 2).

However, the proper approach will be customizing the style through CSS file by overriding the related selectors of listview/listcell.

Additionally keep in mind, the background color of `:odd` rows of listview are derived ones from the above mentioned `-fx-control-inner-background`. And since the pseudo classes (:focused, :hover, :odd etc.) cannot be set through `setStlyle()`, you need to override it in CSS file, if you want it to be another color or no color definition at all.